# Virtual keyboard events does not get triggered on web

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events, virtual-keyboard

I am working on an ASP.net MVC project. I tried to use virtual keyboards in it and the problem I am facing is that the keyboard events don't get triggered on the virtual keyboard. Can anybody suggest a solution to the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 'virtual keyboard' as javascript plugin? If so, the javascript events needs to be made ajax call to MVC action method.

In Asp.Net MVC there is no event concept. It's not event driven model.

Comment: I am using JS plugin but I am using it in my script.
I don't need to do any backend call for 'keyup' events. I don't want to call any action. I have written ajax calls to interact with action methods in other cases.
I just want to catch keyboard 'keyup' or 'keypress' events in script and do operations in the script. The 'keyup', 'keypress' events are working when I press the key on keyboard, but when I press on the same key in the virtual keyboard, the event is not triggered. 
Since I am using the virtual keyboard as a substitute for a physical keyboard, I want all events for work for both.

Comment: which JS plugin are you using for virtual keyboard?

Comment: for example check this out [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/demos/onscreenkeyboard/). Inspect the page and add a 'keypress' or 'keyup' event handler and check. Event will get 'triggered' when press using physical keyboard but wont work when pressed on the virtual keyboard.
1. 
inspect the page and add the event listener 
`$('.input').keyup(function(e) {
    console.log('keyup event detected', this.value);
})`
2. type something in username input using physical keyboard and check.
3. type something using virtual keyboard.

2. will trigger an event but 3. wont

Comment: [this](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Mobile-first-Virtual-Keyboard-Plugin-With-jQuery-Bootstrap-jQBTK/) is the plugin I used

Comment: Can you use `$('.key').mousedown(function(e) {     console.log('mousedown event detected', this.innerText); })`
Basically, the main event is happening mousedown for the virtual keys and then change in input fields

Comment: thanks for you response. But my requirement is different. I want to trigger an event when 'something is typed in an input field'. That's why I wrote 
`$('.input').keyup...`
In the solution you gave, I am able to catch all events of clicks on the virtual keyboard, but I am not able to determine where it was typed.

Comment: You need to add both the eventListerners which will finally call single event like `$('.input').keyup(processInput());, $('.key').mousedown(processInput());`

Comment: I tried this but **'.keyup'** is triggered only when I type in the input box using my _physical keyboard_ (this _does not work_ when I type something using virtual keyboard) and **'.mousedown'** is triggered when I click on the keys where-ever be it, whether in the input or outside it.
I want to trigger an event only when I type something in a particular input and I also need the value typed.